# Is it possible to list all of the Steam games I have downloaded?

Tags: steam

I had about ten games on Steam on my old computer. Most of them were played at least once. Now, I want them on my new computer. However, I don't care about transferring them, I just want to know what they were. Is there a function in Steam that lets me track my download history or something similar?

Comment: As a side note, free to play games only show up for a few reasons:  1. You spent money through Steam on it at some point.  2. You purchased a bundle that included it before it was free (such as Team Fortress 2 from The Orange Box).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Steam client:

1)  Click your username from the top right, then click 'Account Details', to go to your Steam store control page.

2)  From the Steam store control page, under the 'Store & Purchase History' header, click 'View licenses and product key activations'.

This page shows, in chronological order, what games you have acquired and how (Steam store, retail code, complimentary copy, or gift).  Unlike the other methods above, this activation history includes any free games you may have previously installed, but deleted.

Answer (score 9):

There is an additional way to view Steam games you own.

After logging in to Steam you can view your account's licenses by vising this webpage: https://store.steampowered.com/account/licenses/

Answer (score 6):

Link: https://steamcommunity.com/id/PUT_YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID/games/?tab=all

Manual way: Go to your account-name, click on "show my profile", scroll down until you see "games" listed on the right side (probably above "Inventory" and "screenshots") and click it. Then select "all games" and you should see all games you've played at some point.

Answer (score 5):

By simply installing Steam and going to the Library, there should be a list with all the games you own.

If there isn't, still on the Library page there's a search function in the upper left part of the screen. From there, you can access a drop down menu where you can choose what to list.

If you choose "All Games", you should see all the games you own on Steam and can redownload and reinstall whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you have access to your old computer and you haven't yet uninstalled your games/steam yet. If that's gone, I don't belive steam stores any sort of list of everything you've *ever* downloaded.

On any PC with Steam installed you have access to a list of *currently downloaded* titles (it's one of the filter options on the Library page, I forget the exact menu item and I don't have Steam here). The only thing I'm aware of that you can do is manually go down this list and download the same games on the new PC (or alternately copy over the whole Steamapps folder and keep your game content and possibly saves).

Comment: If you set a category on every game you download, then you can tell from your library which games you've at least downloaded, even if they are not currently insalled on that computer. Games with categories that are not installed will be darker in their category list than games that are installed.

Comment: @StarPilot that's also a good idea. I have a "do not want" category all of the crap goes to (why oh why did I start the TF2 beta)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/GigaJunky/SteamManifests

Steam Manifests Data Extractor
A simple nodejs script to get an inventory of installed games details by reading the Steam manifest files

Prerequisites
you will need to install NodeJS https://nodejs.org this has been tested on windows 10 and Ubunutu 18.04 linux You may need to edit the your steam install path (line 3 of steammanifest.js) if you did not select the default.

running
extract the file to your computer and in windows just click on the steammanifests.bat file

or open a command line and cd to the path

```
node steammanifests.js
```

this will generate two json files in the same folder
open the table.html file in you browser
clck on the Open File Button
select the computername-smfdata.json
you should see your sortable list of games populate
click 'Format Steam Manifest Columns CheckBox' to allow addtional filtering
you can also open the computername-smfpaths.json to show your full paths of steam folders
Author
BitJunky - (https://github.com/gigajunky)
License
This project is licensed under the MIT License - see the LICENSE.md file for details

Acknowledgments
http://tabulator.info/ - a great javascript table spreadsheet commponent

Answer (score -2):

You can find it in the Steam library[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything new to the already existing ones. Also, you should avoid one line answer, which is pretty low quality answer.